# Make difference between a value given a date and value of one year before in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, pandas-loc

If someone can help me please. I have a dataframe like this:
[image]

I need to get the difference between the value of a stock in a given year and the value of the same stock one year before and add new columns with the results like this:

[image]

At `1991-01-01` the value of `A` is `3.8100`, and one year before the value was `3.6780`, the difference between those values is `3.8100-3.6780=0.1320` so i need to put the result in a new column in the `1991-01-01`'s row.

I have tried something like this for finding the date of one year before:

```
for i in range(0, len(df.index)):
   for j in range (len(df.columns)+1, 2* len(df.columns)):
      df.loc(i,j) = df.index[i] . relativedelta(years = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`date.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.replace) and [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas-dataframe-apply):

```py
import io

# Test Data
data = io.StringIO("""
DATE,A,B,Z
1990-01-01,3.6780,1.2303,5.1230
1990-01-02,3.6790,1.2502,5.1340
1990-01-03,3.7000,1.2805,5.1840
1991-01-01,3.8100,1.2805,5.1740
1991-01-02,3.8000,1.2805,5.1740
""")
```

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(data)
df["DATE"] = pd.to_datetime(df["DATE"]).dt.date


def get_growth(current_date, dataframe, columns, years=1):

    current_values = dataframe.loc[dataframe["DATE"] == current_date, columns]
    current_values = current_values.reset_index()

    past_date = current_date.replace(year=current_date.year-years)
    past_values = dataframe.loc[dataframe["DATE"] == past_date, columns]
    past_values = past_values.reset_index()

    return (current_values - past_values)[columns].values[0]


df[["Grow A", "Grow B", "Grow Z"]] = df.apply(
    lambda x: get_growth(x["DATE"], df, ["A", "B", "Z"]),
    axis=1,
    result_type="expand",
)
```

The output of `print(df)` for the test data above would be:

```py
          DATE      A        B      Z   Grow A  Grow B  Grow Z
0   1990-01-01  3.678   1.2303  5.123      NaN     NaN     NaN
1   1990-01-02  3.679   1.2502  5.134      NaN     NaN     NaN
2   1990-01-03  3.700   1.2805  5.184      NaN     NaN     NaN
3   1991-01-01  3.810   1.2805  5.174    0.132  0.0502   0.051
4   1991-01-02  3.800   1.2805  5.174    0.121  0.0303   0.040
```

---

Note: This solution assumes that the `DATE` column contains unique values.